# Scoreboard: Searchable, sortable answers with preview

Tags: discussion, userscript, scoreboard

<sub>Not sure if this is suitable for the main page so I post it here.</sub>

Example:

[Say What You See](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/70837/say-what-you-see/108862) ->
https://hunaphu.github.io/g/q/70837.html

Type to filter on a language. Feel free to use it or include it in your question.

Currently updates every 5 minutes (+1 minutes from github pages) if the question has activity. No history, questions are added when they have activity; might change. Parses most standard formulations for bytes but many non-standard are not captured.

###### Questions in comments

1. g, x, w, (a)ll are clickable keyboard shortcuts for predefined filters. (g)eneral (shared by x, w), x for *nix and w for windows.
2. Backend: cron runs a script checking for activity using stackapp api. If any, update the affected questions, process, and write out the tables. cat with html template and commit.
   Instant update could be done using Websockets but that is not officially supported (and keeps disconnecting for me).

There is also an index at https://hunaphu.github.io/g/

Bonus:
Looks decent in Lynx and can be used to browse questions but without sorting.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Cool site! But the way of getting data you seem to be using looks kinda convoluted. I would recommend either A) using GitHub Actions to automatically update the page frequently, or B) fetch the data using client-side JavaScript. Both ways mean you won't have to run a script locally updating it super frequently all day.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what "g", "x" and "w" are supposed to represent (and skimming the source doesn't make it clear either).

Comment: Perhaps not inherently, but just committing all changes to the repo feels weird. I think a site like this doesn't really make sense as a static site.

Comment: It probably wouldn't be noticeably slower, maybe 200ms or so, but it would be way more scalable: for one, you could isolate your changes to the UI from the CRON commits; and for two, as more posts are added to this site the git repo will have to get larger and larger the way you have it, where with a server-side architecture it won't change at all. If I were building a site like this, I would probably go for Next.js on Vercel (which is free unless you have many thousands of users)